# Firebase.auth() not persistant between pages on localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm making a website with Firebase authentication. After the user is logged in in the first page, he can move to another page. The problem is that on the second page the login isn't saved.

I've checked a few questions like this already, but didn't find a solution.
All of the pages are on my computer for now, so localhost in Firebase's Authorized domains should be enough.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        // do things
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        // show option to signup
    }
});
```

I expected that after the login in the previous page, the login to persist to the new page as well. But user is always null, ie not logged in.

**UPDATE:**
I might be wrong, but I think this issue is caused when running the webpage in localhost. Each page is treated as a separated login session. When using github hosting this issue is not present.

Comment: How do you check if the user is signed in or not on the second page? The callback posted is more for being notified if the auth state changed.

Comment: @puelo It's from Firebase's example on how to check authentication status
[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). It is not correct?

Comment: Ah yes. If it is a full page reload i guess it is the correct way. Is it possible that cookies or local storage are deactivated?